# Proving convolution has no identity element (no measure theory)

Tags: calculus, convolution

In my advanced calculus class, we were talking about convolution, and we were asked to prove that there is no **real valued, Riemann integrable** $f\in X$, where $X = \{f | \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|dt < \infty\}$ such that for every **continuous** function $g\in X$, $f*g =g$ ($f$ doesn't have to be continuous). The integrals are all Riemann.

So, my attempt was to define for every $\varepsilon$ the function
$$
g_{\varepsilon}(x) = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{\varepsilon}|x| + 1 & x\in[-\varepsilon, \varepsilon] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

and now, assume $f$ is such identity element. Then
$$
(f*g_{\varepsilon})(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g_{\varepsilon}(x-t)dt = \int\limits_{x-\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon}f(t)g_{\varepsilon}(x-t)dt = g_{\varepsilon}(x)
$$
For $|x| \leq \varepsilon$, 
$$
\int\limits_{x-\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon}f(t)g_{\varepsilon}(x-t)dt = 1
$$
for all epsilon.
The logic behind this attempt is to show that the integral on the left is not continuous which is a contradiction since integral functions are always continuous. I was unable to proceed from here.

I must mention that this class has nothing to do with measure theory, so we are suppose to prove this without the notions of measure, 'almost everywhere' etc.

Comment: Is it valid apply Fourier transform? If it is, the issue becomes "show there are no real-valued, ... with Fourier transform equal to 1".

Comment: No complex analysis, this is all real analysis.

Comment: Your $g_{\epsilon}$ are a good idea. Look specifically at $x = 0$. You would have $$\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt \geqslant 1$$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Are you using in last step that $g_e(x)=1$ if $|x|<e$ ?